# margin of child affect ancestors including body

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

Does anyone have an idea / explanation why this code affects the anchestors in it's vertical position?
This effect take place at least in chrome v75 and firefox v67 on linux.

Actually I would expect:

- no affect on any parent-element of this two children
- the first child on top aligned
- second child followed by first child, fully visible

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/mtinner/full/OKpegE)

```css
.abs {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.static {
  margin-top: 100px;
  background: blue;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="abs">Absolute or fixed should have no space to the top</div>
  <div class="static"></div>
</header>
```

Comment: Juste put your header on position relative and add position absolute; top: 100px; to your second child

Comment: have a read about [collapsing margins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing) (in particular, the section titled **No content separating parent and descendants**) - that is what is causing your gap above the parent, the child's margin top has collapsed outside the parent

Answer (score 0):

like that

```css
.abs {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.static {
  position:absolute;
  top: 100px;
  background: blue;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header style="position:relative;">
  <div class="abs">Absolute or fixed should have no space to the top</div>
  <div class="static"></div>
</header>
```

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately not my question ;-)